# Proof that pointwise continuity implies uniform continuity for functions on compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, compactness

**Theorem:** Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $f : X→\mathbb{R}$ be such that $f$ is pointwise continuous for every $x \in X$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $X$.

I was trying to prove this theorem using the fact that the range of a continuous function on a compact set is a compact set.

For every $\varepsilon >0$ and $x \in X$ define the set $S(x,\varepsilon) = \{\delta>0:d(y,x) < \delta \Rightarrow  d(f(y),f(x)) < \varepsilon\}$.

Now fix an $\varepsilon > 0$, and define $F(\varepsilon)$ to be a set of functions as follows: $F(\varepsilon) = \{\varphi : X→U(\varepsilon)\:\text{such that}\: \varphi(x) \in S(x,\varepsilon) \:\forall x \in X\}$, where $U(\varepsilon) =\bigcup_{x \in X}S(x,\varepsilon)$.
Note that $F(\varepsilon)$ is just the set of all functions that take x in X to a suitable delta.

If we can show that even one element of $F$ is continuous in $X$, then we know that the range of that function must be compact (since $X$ is compact) and hence must contain its infimum (since it is closed and bounded), which means that the $f$ is uniformly continuous in $X$.

Is this last claim even true, if it is how do I go about proving it ?
Thanks

Comment: Thanks, my idea was that for any epsilon greater than zero, we can find a certain minimum delta that works for each x in X, which would imply uniform continuity.

Comment: What does $f(x)\in S(x,\epsilon)$ mean?

Comment: @geetha290krm edited the post,  i meant phi instead of f

Comment: @AnCar I am not sure I see how taking the smallest $\delta$ gives you that $|x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$. If $x,y$ appear in the same $\delta$-ball then they appear in the same $\varepsilon$-ball, so $|f(x)-f(y)|<2\varepsilon$, but $|x-y|<\delta$ does not guarantee that they are in the same $\delta$-ball

Comment: Your solution does seem plausible, but to show that there is a continuous element in $F$ might be harder than the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposed solution in the comments is not correct, here is a counterexample:

Let

\begin{align}
f:\{0,0.5,1\}&\to \mathbb{R}\\
x&\mapsto x
\end{align}

The domain of $f$ is compact, and $f$ is continuous. Suppose we take

$$\varepsilon=0.6$$

Then a suitable $\delta$-ball around $0.5$ would be

$$(-1,2)$$

Which also happens to be a finite cover for the domain, it has a radius of $1.5$, but note that even though

$$|0-1|<1.5$$

We don't have

$$|f(1)-f(0)|<0.6$$

So taking the minimum $\delta$ appearing as a radius of some arbitrary finite sub-cover is not sufficient.

Instead, a sequential argument is helpful here: If we suppose that there is an $\varepsilon_0$ for which there is no minimal $\delta$ that works, we obtain a sequence of elements $(x_n)$ in the domain such that the ball of radius $\frac{1}{n}$ is too *big*, then this sequence has a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ with limit $x_0$ in the domain, this $x_0$ has some $\delta$-ball with radius $\delta_0$ such that

$$ f(B(x_0,\delta_0))\subseteq B(f(x_0,\frac{\varepsilon}{2}) $$
But eventually $(x_{n_k})$ is contained in the ball

$$B(x_0,\frac{\delta_0}{2})$$

Which gives us a contradiction (see if you can find precisely what this contradiction is)

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what got confused in my head, but my comment is definitely wrong. Deleted it.

Comment: @AnCar no worries, I have made the exact same mistake before, actually recently, which is why I recognised it, but I think its instructive to see why it doesn't work